# How to find roots of a non linear multivariable equation using numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

I started a course in linear algebra and numerical methods but I couldn't understand how can we numerically find roots of a nonlinear multivariable equation.

$f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

Find $f(x)=0$ where $x$ is $n$-vector and $f$ maps $n$-vector to scalar value

Thank you!

Update: I meant one equation of several variables not a system of equations.

Comment: Are you meaning ONE equation of SEVERAL variables ?

Comment: I followed the links but it seems to suggest methods for system of non linear equations or unconstrained minimization.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yeah

Comment: Newton's method, in its raw form, cannot be used to find a root of an underconstrained systems of equations (and notice there will typically be an entire manifold of roots).

One modification would be to use the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse:
$$x_n = x_{n-1} - [\nabla f(x_{n-1})]^{+} f(x_{n-1})$$ but I have no personal experience with how well this works in practice.

Comment: What if you set all but one variable to $0$ then solve for the remaining variable?  Not guaranteed to work, but in your application it might be fine.

Comment: It might not work if all the terms are products of two or more variables.

Comment: I was looking at solution to underdetermined system but I wasn't sure if it would work well in this case or if there are better methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, apparently, you speak about a function of multiple variables, the only possible way I can "see" (I am blind !), is to minimize the square of this function hoping that you will find solution for which the value of this squared function is zero.

Then, either you use an optimizer either you try to solve the Jacobian which will lead you to as many equations as variables. For the later case, Newton-Raphson method is one of the solutions to consider (provided you are able to have "reasonable" starting guesses).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that should work. I didn't think about unconstrained minimization of squared f

Comment: @Sagar. You welcome !

Answer (score 0):

One other useful re-interpretation is to include this equation as equality constraint in an optimization problem. For instance, minimize $\|x-a\|^2$ under the constraint $f(x)=0$. Choosing a specific center point, for instance $a=0$, might lead to singularities, choosing a small random point for $a$ gives a greater chance for a regular system. Then solve using your favorite optimization algorithm.